# Show/hide payment gateways based on checkout billing company field is empty in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

Hiding a Payment Gateway: 'Purchase Order' if customer does not have their Billing Company field filled in. We don't allow customers that are not in the US or not a business or institution to use purchase orders and would prefer that the option is hidden otherwise.

```
function payment_enable_manager( $available_gateways ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( isset( $available_gateways['cod'] ) && $woocommerce->customer->get_country() != 'US' && $woocommerce->customer->get_billing_company() === '' ) {
        unset( $available_gateways['cod'] );
    } 

    return $available_gateways;
}
```

Comment: don't just delete and ask the same question, please.

Comment: what is your question? what have you tried?

Comment: @mrkvon My question is that I need to hide the payment gateway 'cod'. I've tried changing the order of  the && statements. I've tried doing get_billing_company = NULL, EMPTY, FALSE, ''. Nothing seems to grab the billing_company and translate that its empty

Comment: Sorry @tim the old posting locked up on me and wouldn't let me edit it, so I just copied the information and deleted the old post.